# Creating a dataframe with stocks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to take information retrieved online and put it into a dataframe and im having trouble figuring out how to go about it im new to this. Any Suggestions would be valuable thank you.

[image: Code for retrieving stock info]
[image]

This is what im trying to get my dataframe to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just append a dictionary to a constructor list while you iterate through the tickers. Something like:

```py
builder = []
for ticker in tickers:
    # set recommendation here
    builder.append({'Company': ticker, 'Recommendation': recommendation})

df = pd.DataFrame(builder)
```